# Use inferred type from union parameter in TypeScript function

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Given type definition with fixed attribute names like

```
type Animals =
  | {
      key: 'dog';
      value: { woof: string };
    }
  | {
      key: 'cat';
      value: { meow: number };
    }
```

How do I construct a function parameters that will guarantee passing correct parameter at compile time to only a single type? I would like to call my function like:

```
fn('dog', { woof: 'woof' });
fn('cat', { meow: 'meow' });
```

but following should fail during compile time

```
fn('dog', { meow: 'meow' });
fn('cat', { woof: 'woof' });
```

I tried `const fn = <T extends Animals>(key: T['key'], value: Extract<T, { key: T['key'] }>['value']) => ...`, however value type remains of union type `{ woof: string } | { meow: number }`, instead of exclusive `{ woof: string }` or `{ meow: number }` based on key parameter.

Comment: Why not just `fn({ key, value }: Animals) {}`. It is not quite the same but it is type safe in the sense that passing the wrong `value` will make it fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do it! To be fair I wasn't sure this was possible!

```
type Value<TKey, TAnimal extends Animals> = TAnimal extends { key: TKey, value: infer TValue } ? TValue : never;

function fn<TKey extends Animals['key'], TAnimal extends Animals>(key: TKey, value: Value<TKey, TAnimal>) {
   // Your code here
}
```

[Take a look at this playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2BnKBeAUFKAHygG98CKBrCEALigHIATAewHMGBuciqAN3QBXCPRJQA7ixYAzehmAAnBHDZQAvt15ryxMrwLU6jAMYpgXHhQFphoqEggtx9OIKQAjCAvWaK23KCQUABqQhAAPAAqANI0ADRQkfDI6FAQAB7AEHBMWMmomAB8OIn5qRlZOVhihvQx8fxh9MrSXomhNtBqUAD87WFQtHAQfF7cuNKCcMbACCxwUNJwUbEgaZnZubCIBRgA2gyGDAC6CUk75RtV2ylFABS1iasJ1rYhYSsN57eFAJSk-lwAHoge80AgmBM4HdmOwGAkSJIZPQGCh3MYGGpflCYaZzAiHE56ABGABMAGYsbhgaCAJJwawQnGwjgIpGyKBkynYpa4szw0iE5yMNEYqm8lkCkgACwgaDQLBRosxPOhDDxUskCjQTBJFPFatYbAwmqkHNR6JVzLxJoJjmFXKxQA).